# how to save images with the save button on the tkinter in python

Tags: python, numpy, tkinter, python-imaging-library, opencv

I tried to make the 'save as' button to save the image in a certain location directory using tkinter but I got a problem

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import ImageTk, Image, ImageDraw
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('face_person1.jpg')
# convert the images to PIL format...
edged = Image.fromarray(img)

edged = ImageTk.PhotoImage(edged)

def savefile():
    hsl = Image.open(edged)
    hsl = filedialog.asksaveasfile(mode='w', defaultextension=".jpg")
    if hsl is None:
        return
    sv = edged.save()
    sv.close()


button = Button(text="save as", command=savefile)
button.pack()
```

The error message is:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback fp = io.BytesIO(fp.read())
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Comment: Try setting up the code to work without Tkinter first (for example, with a hard-coded output filename) so that you can see the entire context of the exception.

Comment: don't use the same variable `edge` for `PIL.Image` and `ImageTk.PhotoImage` if you want to save it because `ImageTk.PhotoImage` doesn't have function to save it. You have to save `PIL.Image`

Comment: you don't have to open it if you want to save it. And don't assing name to variable `hsl` if you have image in this variable

Answer (score 1):

To save image you have to use `PIL.Image` so don't assign `PhotoImage` to variable which you use to keep `PIL.Image`

```
edge = Image.fromarray(img)

tk_edge = ImageTk.PhotoImage(edge)
```

and you have to use filename to save it

```
edge.save(filename)
```

Full working example

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import ImageTk, Image, ImageDraw
import cv2
import numpy as np

# --- functions ---

def savefile():
    filename = filedialog.asksaveasfile(mode='w', defaultextension=".jpg")
    if not filename:
        return
    edge.save(filename)

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

img = cv2.imread('face_person1.jpg')
edge = Image.fromarray(img)

tk_edge = ImageTk.PhotoImage(edge)
label = tk.Label(root, image=tk_edge)
label.pack()

button = tk.Button(root, text="save as", command=savefile)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```